# (Error while establishing TCP connection)

Tags: c, couchbase

I'm having a problem, couldn't find the solution in the internet.

I'm trying to compile and run this code: [couchbase example](http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-c-client-2.4.1/example_2minimal_2minimal_8c-example.html)

Compiling with: gcc -Wall -g -o main main.c  -lcouchbase (It compiles fine).

running with: ./main couchbase://127.0.0.1:8092/user1 pass

after calling `lcb_get_bootstrap_status(instance)`, it says:

> (Error while establishing TCP connection)

Yes, I have created the 'user1' bucket, with password: 'pass', and I have disabled iptables too.

I'm using couchbase-server 2.5.1, on ubuntu 14.04

So, can anyone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Port 8092 is not the correct port, in fact it is the view API (CAPI, couch API, map reduce etc.) port. You should typically not place the port unless your server is configured to listen on a non standard port in the first place.

Comment: You saved me a lot of time, mate. Thanks a lot